# what is the starting path for relative path file imports in spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, relative-path

I'm trying to import a spring config.xml from outside the jar file.  There is an annotation config class that makes the import into the config

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("file:config.xml")
public class SpringConfig {
   ...
}
```

The log messages from spring indicate that it cannot find the config.xml.  But they do not say what is the path where it is searching for this config.xml.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

In the development environment

```
src\main\java\
|__com.packagewithclasses
|__config.xml
|__log4j.xml
```

In the live environment

```
folder_holding_jars_and_configs
|__executable_jar_file.jar
|__config.xml
|__log4j.xml
```

I have tried the docs, google, some wildcards, logs, etc.  No luck.  What is spring's start path for relative paths to config outside the jar file?

Comment: You should almost never use file: for resources, all resources should be loaded from the classpath. This ensures that it works on every developer machine, and when built from maven/gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give absolute path of the file in case the file is outside the jar.

e.g.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("file:/opt/proj/config.xml")
public class SpringConfig {
   ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Apart from above, you can put the relative path to your XML file in `MANIFEST.MF` file. Since your jar and XML is in same directory you can put the following line in `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Class-Path: .
```

*`MANIFEST.MF` requires a blank line at the end of file.*

Now you can use the xml file like below.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("file:/config.xml")
public class SpringConfig {
   ...
}
```

Location of `MENIFEST.MF` would be `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' for maven project.

Comment: That can't be right.  That would require that the absolute path be baked into the jar file.  Moving that jar file to another environment would break it because the absolute path may be different in another environment. How could one make portable no-recompile user provided configs?

Comment: you are right, that's why you have to create the file at the same path in each environment

Comment: It must look *somewhere* for the file before it decides it can't find it? Right?

Comment: you can consider using a property place holder ${path.file} and provide the property as JVM property -Dpath.file="absolute path"

Comment: I have updated my answer, this might fulfil your criteria.

Comment: Absolutely did.  Thanks.